# Print the Letter X on a Background Console

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I have been asked to solve this algorithm. And so far this is what I have regarding the java code. I don't know where I am missing something. The problem is as follows:
Write a Class called ProblemA003 that output's the following shape (which is the letter X using “$” symbols on a background console):

> Simply output to the console (using system.out)
>   Assume a console screen of 25 lines deep and 79 chars wide (see below for the console – it comprises “=” character, with relevant numbering for every 10th column and row.
>   The shape must be centered on this console screen i.e. the middle “$” should be in row 13, column 40
>   Take as an input to the program a single int parameter (which you can name sizeOfX). This parameter will indicate how many "$" are in the X on either side of the middle “$”. You can simply pass this parameter in via the “main” method. For a clearer description of the parameter sizeOfX, see the example below when sizeOfX = 5
>   Note: parameter sizeOfX must only take on values of 1-9 (inclusive of 1 and 9). Of course, the bigger the value of sizeOfX, the bigger the size of the X your program must produce.

my method:

```
private static void MakeACross(int number) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = number - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        System.out.print("==");
        for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
            System.out.print("==");
            if (start == end && j == i) {
                System.out.print('$');
            } else if (start == j || end == j) {
                System.out.print('$');
            } else {
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
        }
        start++;
        end--;
        System.out.println("==");
    }
}
```

Anyone who can help me on how I can further solve this will be highly appreciated.

the output should be ass follows: if the input is 5 (i.e. sizeOfX = 5), your program should produce EXACTLY the output (note the “1” and “2” in the first column of row 10 and 20 respectively)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that would work

```
   public void PrintX(int number)
    {


        int headLoc = 0, tailLoc = number - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            string line = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < number; j++)
            {
                if (j == headLoc || j == tailLoc)
                {
                    line += "=";
                }
                else
                {
                    line += " ";
                }
            }

            headLoc++;
            tailLoc--;
            System.out.println(line);

        }


    }
```